# C# XElement - Parent property

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xmldocument, weak-references

Does the XElement Parent property wrap a weak or a strong reference?

My code currently uses XmlElement, which holds a strong reference (ParentNode), and I'm considering the benefits of replacing it with XDocument.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.weakreference.aspx)? If so, no, the parent property of an `XElement` is not a `WeakReference`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't save any memory be switching from `XmlDocument` to `XDocument`. All references are strong. If you have a refernce to any element, you force the whole document to remain in memory.

The choice between `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` is about horrible vs. nice API, not about memory.

Comment: Agreed. LINQ to XML is not meant to save memory, but to save sanity when working with XML data...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to work with only small part of the original XML, and must discard the rest, consider making a clone of the elements you are interested in.

See - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297950(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public XElement(XElement other)
```

This constructor makes a deep copy of an element.